# Is it a violation of Google Play Policies to forward the user to a book sale page via my app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, privacy-policy

Can anyone tell me if it's a violation of Google Play policies to forward the user to a book sale page via my app?
As a developer, can I use a button to forward the user to a book page on a book sales website?
Note: The book will not be consumed within the app.

Comment: Are you navigating the user to a webpage via other installed browser on the phone or via in-app WebView implementation?

Comment: @DarShan To a webpage via other installed browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can, **BUT** you should tag the button with an `Ad` tag (like the image below)

[image]

This happened to me before in one of my apps and the Google Play Policy team asked me to clarify it is an Ad even though it linked to my own page.

Comment: Thanks Jabbar! But imagine the situation: The user see a list of books in a recyclerView on "MainActivity" and when the user touchs any book of the list, the app opens the "BookDetailsActivity" to see book details and in this activity user touchs in a button called "Buy" and now the user go to the book saller website. It's ok or is a violation? The "Ad" tag on the button will works on this situation, on the book details activity only or I have to put an another "Ad" tag on each card of book  in the recyclerView too?

Sorry for my english...

Comment: @juhchamp you should put the "Ad" tag on the button that take the user out of your app to the seller website only.

Comment: I will launch this and see what happens. Thanks for the answers.